# Getting race condition despite protecting write operations - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Using the java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock library as follows:

Two threads generate a random number and use it to update the shared variables account1 and account2 stored in class Accounts - a lock is used to protect the writing to the shared vars

```
package osproj221;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Accounts {
    private int account1,account2;
    private final ReentrantLock mutex;

    public Accounts(){
        account1=account2=0;
        mutex = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public void updateAccounts(int amt){
        try{
            mutex.lock();
            account1 += amt;
            account2 -= amt;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }finally{mutex.unlock();}
    }

    public int getAccount1(){
        return this.account1;
    }

    public int getAccount2(){
        return this.account2;
    }
}
```

My threads implement the Runnable interface as follows:

```
package osproj221;
import java.util.Random;

public class RaceThread implements Runnable {

    private Random myRand = new Random();
    private int counter = 0;
    private Accounts accounts;

    public RaceThread(Accounts accounts){
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }

    public void run(){

        do{
            int r = myRand.nextInt(300);
            r = Math.abs(r);
            accounts.updateAccounts(r);
            counter++;
        }while((accounts.getAccount1() + accounts.getAccount2() == 0));

        System.out.println(counter + " " + accounts.getAccount1() + " " + accounts.getAccount2());
    }

}
```

and finally my Main class

```
package osproj221;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Accounts myAccounts = new Accounts();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new RaceThread(myAccounts));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new RaceThread(myAccounts));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try{
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        System.out.println(myAccounts.getAccount1() + " " + myAccounts.getAccount2());

    }

}
```

that looks a little longer than i thought it would - apologies. I would expect that neither of the threads would terminate, because account1+account2 should always = 0 as the mutex handles protecting the updating of account1 and account2. What seems to happen is that one of the threads exits because it fails the account1+account2==0 condition, and the other one continues indefinitely. im confused!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're not locking the reads on your getters. This means thread 2 can read the data in an inconsistent state, while thread 1 is updating the data (between += and -=). 
The problem can happen as follows:

*Thread 1:*

1. updateAccounts(5);
2. OBTAIN LOCK
3. account1 += 5; -> account1 = 0 + 5; -> account1 = 5;

*Thread 2:*

1. getAccount1() <- returns 5
2. getAccount2() <- returns 0
3. 5+0 != 0 --> EXIT

*Thread 1:*

1. account2 -= 5 -> account2 = 0-5 -> account2 = -5;
2. RELEASE LOCK.

**The solution:**
Unfortunately you can't simply synchonize your getters individually I would instead recommend a new get method:

```
public int getAccountsSum() {
    try {
        mutex.lock();
        return this.account1 + this.account2;
    } finally { mutex.unlock(); }
```

and in `RaceThread.run()` change the while condition to:

```
    }while((accounts.getAccountsSum() == 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to synchronize your writes; you also need to synchronize your reads, using the same lock/monitor.

If you don't, bad things can happen:

- There is no guarantee that a write on one thread will *ever* be visible to an unsynchronized reader on another thread.
- Even if the writes are visible, there is no guarantee that they will become visible in the expected order, or that your two unsynchronized reads will see coherent values for the different variables. It's quite possible for you to see an old value of `account1` and a new value of `account2`, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

you are only syncronizing the write access to the variables.

so there is a chance of one thread setting account1 to a new value while the other is reading an old account2.

Answer (score 0):

Your Getters are not locked. So even though you use a mutex on updating the other thread is calling the Getters which can run unlocked.

- Thread1:
- - updateAccounts
- - - LOCK
- - - account1 += r
- Thread2:
- - getAccount1
- - getAccount2
- - account1 + account2 != 0
- Thread1:
- - - account2 -= r
- - - UNLOCK

  public int getAccounts(){
      int result = 0;
      try{
          mutex.lock();
          result = account1 + account2;
      }catch(Exception ex){
          System.out.println(ex);
      }finally{mutex.unlock();}
      return result;
  }